# ViewDragHelper: how to use it?

Tags: android, drag, slide

In the Google IO 2013, Google has announced a new version of the Support Library, which includes `ViewDragHelper` class.
I saw the docs, but I couldn't find any sample of usage for this class.

For example, a very typical situation: I have a custom view, which extends from `FrameLayout` and allows to drag some of the `View`s inside. For example, let it be a `Button`. I override `onTouchEvent()` and `onInterceptTouchEvent()` within my custom view, and if the button of the rect contains the touch coordinates and this is not a simple click, then I start to drag.

So, what I must do with `ViewDragHelper` to get that? The clicks to the `Button` should process correctly.

Comment: You can try to check this project on Git Hub : https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Actually I am trying to find out how it works right now. Currently I stacked on on a moment where I can't find any ViewDragHelper in my support library jar. :)

Comment: This class would be in only last version of Support Library, dated May 2013. Try to update your Support Library via SDKManager. Look in `android.v4.support.widget` package.

Comment: Have you managed to get a Button that handles both clicks and drags ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is a good example shows how ViewDragHelper is used.
https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Use `ViewDragHelper.create()` method to create it. Use the `shouldInterceptTouchEvent()` to determine if you should intercept the touch event from child views.

Use `smootSlideViewTo()` method to move the child view within your customized view.

Comment: smootSlideViewTo is not working for me. Als o i cannot find any examples hw to use it (except SlidingUpPanel)

Answer (score 19):

Here is a nice post about how to use `ViewDragHelper`

- [each-navigation-drawer-hides-a-viewdraghelper](http://old.flavienlaurent.com/blog/2013/08/28/each-navigation-drawer-hides-a-viewdraghelper/)

Comment: link is broken.

Comment: http://old.flavienlaurent.com/blog/2013/08/28/each-navigation-drawer-hides-a-viewdraghelper/

Comment: @shaobin0604 I found your article very enlightening, and have almost modified the ```YoutubeLayout``` class so I can use it with my own content (2 linear layouts, with very diverse content). However, I find a bit difficult to make some tweaks to the class, although I believe is related with my short knowledge of the ```ViewDragHelper```. Do you think is it possible to make the content not to fully take the height of the screen? I'd like it to stick with my defined ```android:layout_height="wrap_content"``` , and at the moment, it's ignoring it.

Comment: nice tutorial really helpful