# Swipe/drag Android view from the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I want to do in my app a View that I can swipe from the bottom of the window (Images below explain it better).

I want the view to stop at certain point. The view must allow to swipe/drag it to the bottom again. Any idea or tip of how can I do that?

[image: This is what I want to have initially]

[image]

Comment: Hi Can you please help me , i want require same.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you are in search of a `ViewDragHelper`:

API doc:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/ViewDragHelper.html

How to use. This answer links to a sample project to show you how as well:
[ViewDragHelper: how to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772532/viewdraghelper-how-to-use-it)

Dragging best practices:

http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale.html

Answer (score 11):

You can use the new material design pattern called Bottom Sheets.
They do the exact thing that you want. They also support custom layouts for the view.

[Material Design - Component - Bottom Sheets](https://material.io/design/components/sheets-bottom.html)

Comment: Perfect solution